# Boolean algebra leading leading to an output greater than one?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

To my understanding, logic gates take two inputs and give out one input. Consider the or gate below:

[image]

Since the output is \$A + B\$ suppose that \$A=1\$ and \$B=1\$ (i.e: both wires have current through them).. this would mean that \$A+B=2\$ but it is supposed to be that the or gate outputs out in binary. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Sorry to be a critique here, but someone has to give a right advice to you. I am volunteering. It is easy to give you the answer, since your question is primitive. And, doing so does not benifit you nor the site, in my opinion. So, I should recommend you more reading and to establish a little more fundamentals about math and logic, before you dive into the problem solving.

Comment: I accept what you said, and you needn't be sorry for it because I think it is a 100% correct. But, I am in an exam which requires me to study this specific way...and that's why. You can look up the JEE exam of India

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Boolean logic the '**+**' means **OR**, not plus.

- \$ A + B = A \ \text {OR}\ B \$
- \$ A \cdot B = A \ \text {AND}\ B \$

The rules of logic are not the same as the rules of addition.

```
A  B | OR      A  B | AND
-----+---      -----+----
0  0 | 0       0  0 | 0
1  0 | 1       1  0 | 0
0  1 | 1       0  1 | 0
1  1 | 1       1  1 | 1
```

Binary logic can only be true or false, 0 or 1, low or high. There are only two possible states.

Comment: In some cases, inputs can be declared to be "don't care". Although, yes, they have to be either 0 or 1. Just saying. Well, quibbling, really. Sorry.